# How to reduce audio data recorded with ENCODING_PCM_16BIT and sample rate 8000 Hz?

Tags: java, android, react-native, audio, websocket

My goal is to reduce the audio data size generated by the [react-native-recording](https://github.com/qiuxiang/react-native-recording).

The expected result:
The audio file size should be between 5200 bytes to 5400 bytes per 1 seconds of audio / Opus Voice bit rate 5.17 KiB with sampling rate 8 kHz.

The actual result:
The audio file size is 3 times the expected result. For example recording this word `A guest for Mr. Jerry` / 1.6 seconds of audio will have a data size roughly 28,000 bytes.

### Important

I plan to write custom native module to achieve this goal. If you like, feel free to leave a link for me to read.

### TL:DR

My end goal is to send the audio data through WebSocket. I deliberately remove the WebSocket.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Add listener

```
  let audioInt16: number[] = [];
  let listener;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    listener = Recording.addRecordingEventListener((data: number[]) => {
      console.log('record', data.length);
      // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
      audioInt16 = audioInt16.concat(data);
    });

    return () => {
      listener.remove();
    };
  });
```

2. Record audio

```
  const startAsync = async () => {
    await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.RECORD_AUDIO,
    ]);

    Recording.init({
      bufferSize: 4096,
      sampleRate: 8000,
      bitsPerChannel: 16,
      channelsPerFrame: 1,
    });

    Recording.start();
  };
```

3. Save audio

```
  const saveAudio = async () => {
    const promise = await RNSaveAudio.saveWav(path, audioInt16);
    console.log('save audio', promise, path);
  };
```

4. Play audio

```
  const playAudio = () => {
    if (player.canPrepare || player.canPlay) {
      player.prepare((err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        console.log('play audio', player.duration);
        player.play();
      });
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

I just did the calculations, with sampleRate of 8000, and mono channel with 16-bits (2-bytes) per sample, that's 16,0000 bytes per second, so 1.6 seconds of audio is 25,600 bytes, which is what you're getting.

To get 5200 to 5400 bytes per second, you have to work backwards.
Select 8-bit (1-byte) per sample. So you only have 5200 to 5400 sampleRate to work with.

PCM data is raw audio samples. The only way to get higher quality audio into less bytes is by audio compression, into mp3 or aac or some other audio compression codec.

---

Original reply:

Looks like RNSaveAudio.saveWav has a fixed sampleRate of 44100:

https://github.com/navrajkambo/RNSaveAudio/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/navraj/rnsaveaudio/RNSaveAudioModule.java

```
            output = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path));
            // WAVE header
            // see http://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/
            writeString(output, "RIFF"); // chunk id
            writeInt(output, 36 + data.length); // chunk size
            writeString(output, "WAVE"); // format
            writeString(output, "fmt "); // subchunk 1 id
            writeInt(output, 16); // subchunk 1 size
            writeShort(output, (short) 1); // audio format (1 = PCM)
            writeShort(output, (short) 1); // number of channels
            writeInt(output, 44100); // sample rate
            writeInt(output, 44100 * 2); // byte rate
            writeShort(output, (short) 2); // block align
            writeShort(output, (short) 16); // bits per sample
            writeString(output, "data"); // subchunk 2 id
            writeInt(output, data.length); // subchunk 2 size
```

You can simply write your own WAVE file writer based on this example
More on Wave format:
http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I did change the sampling rates to 8000 in `RNSaveAudio.saveWav`. The actual result above I stated earlier is with sampling rates to 8000.

Comment: So in theory, if I want to use it for audio streaming. I need to create a custom audio compressor and say, I compress the audio for every 1s. Or is there alternative beside PCM?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to look into sox. Its open source and can do this and much much more.
http://sox.sourceforge.net/

e.g.

`sox <in file> -r <new sample rate> <out file>`

```
soxi 332188.flac
Input File     : '332188.flac'
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 384000
Precision      : 16-bit
Duration       : 00:00:02.01 = 770048 samples ~ 150.4 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 836k
Bit Rate       : 3.34M
Sample Encoding: 16-bit FLAC
Comment        : 'Comment=Processed by SoX'

sox 332188.flac -r 48000 332188_new_sample_rate.flac

soxi 332188_new_sample_rate.flac
Input File     : '332188_new_sample_rate.flac'
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 48000
Precision      : 16-bit
Duration       : 00:00:02.01 = 96256 samples ~ 150.4 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 114k
Bit Rate       : 456k
Sample Encoding: 16-bit FLAC
Comment        : 'Comment=Processed by SoX'
```