# Compressing mp3 audio in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there any way to compress mp3 audio in react js

I record audio using AudioReactRecorder and save the url as mp3. Then, I upload the audio in react-s3 aws. In my webpage, I recorded an audio for just 24 seconds, but the size of this audio is 4.5mb. How can I reduce the bitrate of mp3 audio while saving to aws.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reduce audio data recorded with ENCODING\_PCM\_16BIT and sample rate 8000 Hz?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65406543/how-to-reduce-audio-data-recorded-with-encoding-pcm-16bit-and-sample-rate-8000-h)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that there’s good solution to do it in browser. Use Lambda Function before save it to s3.

You can try this one:
https://github.com/zhuker/lamejs

Or try to limit bitRate before recording

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if that helps but try another package
check this tutorial:
https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/recording-audio-in-mp3-using-reactjs-under-5-minutes-5e960defaf10

hope helps :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).